# T-SQL : convert(datetime) to include/exclude certain hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date, datetime

Using date range to select values, but also need to use an hour range to determine if a record should be selected. The date ranges and time ranges are not necessarily associated.

```
 game_time (between 6 am and 6 pm)
```

have tried straight between statement and datepart, but cannot get anything to capture what we need.

```
create table gametime(name varchar, start_time datetime, end_time datetime)

insert assorted name, start_times and end_times
```

Desired results

```
  name    start_time    end_time
  name1   8:00 AM         10:00 AM
  name2   8:00 AM         11:30 AM
  name3   4:00 PM           5:30 PM
  name4   6:00 PM           9:00 PM
```

`datetime` is used is storage, but not needed in presentation.. only times are needed in presentation.

Selected games should only start between the hours of 6:00 AM and 6:00 PM.

Any and all suggestions and insight appreciated......

Using

```
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), start_time, 100), 7))
```

to get the correct format for presentation,

but when I try to use

```
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), start_time, 100), 7)) > 6
```

I get conversion errors.

Comment: going to need more code -- typically you would use a datetime-- are you not using a datetime?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what results you are really looking for.

Comment: yes, using current_timestamp.  current_timestamp +.5 picks up correct group, but also need to exclude those not within time from a of 6 am 6 p,m.

Comment: question edited to include sample data and desired results.. thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `DATEPART` rather than relying on converting to/comparing strings:

```
WHERE DATEPART(hour,start_time) BETWEEN 6 AND 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Try CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),start_time,108) BETWEEN '06:00' AND '18:00'. Right now you're trying to compare a string to an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will go with the datepart from D Stanley, and remove the comparisons, but your solution indeed works..

Comment: Be careful only going with hour - if the actual time is 18:30, only searching the hour would count that as valid (don't know if you have partial hours to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, provided you're on SQL Server 2008 or higher and have the `TIME` type available:

```
SELECT *
FROM gametime
WHERE CAST(start_time AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:00:00' and '18:00:00'
```

This can be a bit more flexible when your time range is not anchored to exact hours. It also is sarg-able -- i.e. it will use an index, where calling `DATEPART` will prevent that.